# A music file works fine when I pass URI, but It does not work when I pass a String path. Why?

Tags: java, file

I am making a DJ MAX style game.

I am trying to set background music for the game's main screen, but here I found an issue.

When I pass the file's path as a URI or String to instantiate a File object, both work fine.

However, when I try to connect the File object to the FileInputStream, the File object that has a String path does not work (URI FILE WORKS PERFECT). It raises an error that says "The system cannot find the path specified." I checked multiple times, but the path is correct.

Is there any reason why I should pass the path to the File class as a URI?

Thank you for your support

Attributes

```
    public class Music extends Thread {
        private Player player;
        private boolean isLoop;
        private File file;
        private FileInputStream fis;
        private BufferedInputStream bis;
```

Passing the path as a String: Does not work

```
   public Music(String name, boolean isLoop) {
            try {
                this.isLoop = isLoop;
                file = new File("../musics/adventuresHimitsu.mp3");         
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);        
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                player = new Player(bis);
            }catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Raised an error message: 
..\musics\adventuresHimitsu.mp3 (The system cannot find the path specified)
null

Passing the path as a URI: Works

```
    public Music(String name, boolean isLoop) {
    try {
        this.isLoop = isLoop;
        file = new File(Main.class.getResource("../musics/adventuresHimitsu.mp3").toURI());         
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);        
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        player = new Player(bis);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: because when you specified new file you must give a full path (absolute). When you load it from a resource it loaded from current class so the path of relative to the path.

Comment: The first snippet tries to find a file on the file system, using a path that is relative to the current directory, i.e. the directory from which the `java` command was executed. The second snippet tries to load a resource from the classpath, loaded by the class loader, using an invalid path. They do entirely different things. You need to decide what your code is **supposed** to do: load a file on the file system, or load a resource bundled with your application (typically inside the jar file of your application). If the latter, read the javadoc of Class.getResource.

Comment: Also, if the latter, realize that a classpath resource is **not** a file, and you should thus NOT use file IO to read it since, once you'll actually build your app, the resource will be located inside the jar file of your app, and not on the file system.

Comment: What JB Nizet said.  Use `Main.class.getResourceAsStream("../musics/adventuresHimitsu.mp3")` and do not use File or FileInputStream at all.

Comment: @VGR no, because ../musics/adventuresHimitsu.mp3 is not a valid path for getResourceAsStream().

Comment: @JBNizet I tend to agree, though the docs don’t seem to explicitly forbid it.  I just noticed Main extends Thread, though, so ../musics/adventuresHimitsu.mp3 almost certainly will fail.  I guess Tom wanted `getResourceAsStream("/musics/adventuresHimitsu.mp3")`.